# Partitioning (and splitting) values to fill slots

Tags: postgresql

I have some sales data and I need to dispatch the quantities in available slots stored in a separate table.

Example of sales data:

| id | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 9 |

`create table sales (id serial primary key, qty int);`

`INSERT INTO sales (qty) VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(3),(9);`

And here are the slots (size is cumulative):

| name | size |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 9 |

There is an "invisible" `d` slot for the remaining quantities. Of course, these slots are not fixed.

`create table slots (id serial primary key, name text, size int);`

`insert into slots (name,size) values ('a',3),('b',5),('c',9);`

This is the detailed process of the calculation (and expected result):

| id | qty | used | total | slot | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | a |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | a |  |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | a | Slot is full |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | b |  |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 5 | b | split this sale |
| 5 | cont. | 2 | 6-7 | c |  |
| 6 | 9 | 2 | 8-9 | c |  |
| 6 | cont. | 7 | 10-16 | d | split again |

My approach is the following:

```
WITH p1 AS (
    select sales.*,sum(qty) over (order by sales.id) AS tot 
    from sales 
    order by sales.id
)
, p2 AS (
    select p1.id
        ,p1.qty
        , 1+COALESCE(LAG(tot) OVER (ORDER BY p1.id) ,0) AS lag
        , p1.tot
    from p1
)
,p3 AS (
    SELECT id,qty,lag,tot
        , COALESCE( (SELECT id FROM slots WHERE lag<=size ORDER BY size LIMIT 1) , 999) AS slotmin
        , COALESCE( (SELECT id FROM slots WHERE tot<=size ORDER BY size LIMIT 1) , 999) AS slotmax
    FROM p2
)
SELECT p3.id
    ,p3.qty
    -- ,p3.lag
    -- ,p3.tot
    -- ,p3.slotmin
    -- ,p3.slotmax
    ,COALESCE(slots.size-lag+1,p3.qty) AS qtyconsumed
    ,1 AS so
from p3
LEFT JOIN slots ON slots.id=p3.slotmin AND slotmin<>slotmax
UNION
SELECT p3.id
    ,p3.qty
    -- ,p3.lag
    -- ,p3.tot
    -- ,p3.slotmin
    -- ,p3.slotmax
    ,COALESCE(p3.qty-(slots.size-lag+1),0) AS qtyconsumed
    ,2 AS so
from p3
LEFT JOIN slots ON slots.id=p3.slotmin
WHERE slotmin<>slotmax
ORDER BY id,so
```

*I deliberately left some commented columns to ease understanding/debugging my mental process*

Which gives the following result:

```
 id | qty | qtyconsumed | so 
----+-----+-------------+----
  1 |   1 |           1 |  1
  2 |   1 |           1 |  1
  3 |   1 |           1 |  1
  4 |   1 |           1 |  1
  5 |   3 |           1 |  1
    |     |           2 |  2
  6 |   9 |           2 |  1
    |     |           7 |  2
(8 lignes)
```

The code is pretty ugly and will only work for one split: I could very well have only one sale of qty=20 that should split to 4 slots.

My question unfolds in 2 parts:

1. Is it possible to do that splitting in more than 2 slots without going through the mess of cursors or solutions alike? I am guessing *WITH RECURSIVE* but there could be something smarter.
2. How can I optimize this (particularly the search for the closest slot in `p3`) because the real case involves millions of rows?

Comment: (a) In your example, you fill in the slots a,b,c,d in this order. Is it the general rule or is there an other logic in the order of the slots ? (b) What do mean by "search for the closest slot in p3" ? (c) What happen with millions of rows : the first quantities will fulfill the slots a,b,c and all the rest will be in slot d ?

Comment: (a) Sorry, "size" is not a proper name here. Yes, the size of the slots is always growing and cumulative: slot1.size<slot2.size<slot3.size... So in my example, a.realsize=3, b.realsize=2, c.realsize=4
(b) In the p3 CTE (with) I search for the closest slot with a subselect for every row which looks very suboptimal.
(c) Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I propose you a different approach based on the [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and [range operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) :**

First we can calculate the range of quantities for every sale in the sales id order :

```
SELECT id, qty
     , int4range
          ( (1 + sum(qty) OVER w - qty) :: integer
          , sum(qty) OVER w :: integer
          , '[]'
          ) AS sale_range
  FROM sales
WINDOW w AS (ORDER by id)
 ORDER BY id
```

Then we can calculate the range of sizes for every slot in the slot size order :

```
SELECT name, size
     , int4range
          ( (1 + sum(size) OVER w - COALESCE(size, 0)) :: integer
          , CASE WHEN size IS NULL THEN NULL :: integer ELSE sum(size) OVER w :: integer END
          , '[]'
          ) AS slot_range
  FROM slots
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY size)
 ORDER BY size
```

Finally we can simply `JOIN` both sub queries while testing the overlap between the sales ranges and the slots ranges in the `ON` clause. For the rows which match, the intersection between the sales range and the slot range provides the `total` value as expected, and the length of the intersected ranges (`upper(range) - lower(range)`) provides the `used` quantity :

```
WITH sales_ranges AS
(
SELECT id, qty
     , int4range
          ( (1 + sum(qty) OVER w - qty) :: integer
          , sum(qty) OVER w :: integer
          , '[]'
          ) AS sale_range
  FROM sales
WINDOW w AS (ORDER by id)
-- ORDER BY id -- this ORDER BY is useless here
), slots_ranges AS
(
SELECT name, size
     , int4range
          ( (1 + sum(size) OVER w - COALESCE(size, 0)) :: integer
          , CASE WHEN size IS NULL THEN NULL :: integer ELSE sum(size) OVER w :: integer END
          , '[]'
          ) AS slot_range
  FROM slots
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY size)
-- ORDER BY size -- this ORDER BY is useless here
)
SELECT sa.id, sa.qty
     , upper(rg.range) - lower(rg.range) AS used
     , CASE
         WHEN upper(rg.range) = lower(rg.range) + 1
         THEN lower(rg.range) :: text
         ELSE lower(rg.range) || '-' || upper(rg.range) - 1
       END AS total
     , so.name AS slot
  FROM sales_ranges AS sa
 INNER JOIN slots_ranges AS so
    ON sa.sale_range && so.slot_range -- both ranges overlap
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT sa.sale_range * so.slot_range) AS rg(range) -- compute the intersection of both ranges
```

The proposed solution assumes that slot "d" is created in table "slots" with a `NULL` size.

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a687b5022e5658cc063f5fcb7fbe0726)

Comment: Nice usage of ranges! +1 just for this.

Comment: Brilliant solution. There is a little misunderstanding on what I meant by "size": now I know I should have called it the **upper bound**. So to match my initial result I just changed: int4range( COALESCE(Lag(size) over w,0)+1 ,size ,'[]' ) AS slot_range. This is very elegant, thank you for the lesson !